# Newly added tags are not properly url-encoded

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching, ignored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [After adding an interesting tag, the href is not URL encoded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40895/after-adding-an-interesting-tag-the-href-is-not-url-encoded)

When I add c# as an "Interesting Tag" the link will be:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#

This seems correct but the site will be showing tags that contain just 'c' and not 'c#'. After the page has been refreshed the correct link will be displayed:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23

Would it be possible to immediately escape the # char when the user has just added it?