# After adding an interesting tag, the href is not URL encoded

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching, url-encoding

I accidentally deleted my C# tag, but when I re-added it and clicked on it to get a list of questions tagged C#, I noticed the `#` was not URL encoded to `%23`, so I only saw questions tagged `c`.

Comment: I didn't understand at first, but this *only* occurs for the Ajax-added tags; after a page refresh the encoding is fine. Note that after adding a tag, doing a View Source (or Inspect Element) may show `<a href="/questions/tagged/c%23" ..>`, but actually clicking the tag reveals that indeed the percent-encoding is missing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this (I use Google Chrome 5, if that is of significance). I noticed that my existing C# tag is encoded correctly, but any new tag added that contains `#` is not encoded.

It also happens (as would be expected) with other characters such as `{` or `}`.